# GitHub API: Fetch all folders and Files in Single GET Request

Tags: github, github-api

In the GitHub API, I can issue a GET request of

`https://api.github.com/repos/owner/repo/git/trees/master?recursive=1`

to recursively fetch all of the trees of a repository. In addition to giving me all of the directories, it gives me URLs that I can use to download individual files:

```
[...]
{
    "mode": "100644",
    "type": "blob",
    "sha": "abc1234",
    "path": "path/to/file.txt",
    "size": 104361,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/owner/repo/git/blobs/abc1234"
},
[...]
```

While the `recursive=1` piece prevents me from having to make a new GET request for every directory in the repository, I still have to make an individual call for every file. I've looked through the [GitHub API Docs](http://developer.github.com/v3/), but they don't present a way to do this. It's very likely that there simply isn't a way to fetch all files and folders in a single request, but I wanted to ask here to verify that I have no other option.

Comment: Please give some info why you need all the files. Do you use them on some server side application, or is this called in the browser?

Comment: I need to import all of the files in the repository to display them on their associated web site. It's a collection of documentation files that are updated through Git, and imported into the web site.

Comment: Imported how? Why do you need to use the API and not download the zip, or just clone the project?

Comment: I'm currently working with importing the zip file now, and will return to this question if I need to go back to using the REST API. Also, does it really matter why I need to do it? I'm only seeking an answer of how to do it...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only way to do it with a single request is to get the current contents as an archive:
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#download-a-repository-archive

Actually, it's 2 requests since the initial response is a 302 redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to make individual `GET`s for each of those URLs provided by the API. You should check the headers on the responses you get for either 'ETag' or 'Last-Modified' values and use those to prevent having to re-download the file every time your website is queried. Assuming the content has changed, you'll also save your ratelimit.